# Android make FAB not active to single click but active for long click

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I Wonder if the issue I mentioned about in title is possible. I do not want floating action button to be grayed out because it would not be active for long clicks. I want it to be intact when onClick, but reacting on onLongClick. How to do that?

FAB lays on top of custom SurfaceView so It intercepts the click of the place it is located, but I want this behaviour only when onLongClick, if simple onClick I do not want want it to react.

Solution can be both in Java or Kotlin.

Thank you!

Comment: What is "intact" when clicked?
What is "reacting" on long click?
If you don't want to do something onclick, don't set a click listener.
If you want to do something on long click, set a long click listener.

Comment: Yes but this FAB lays on top of custom SurfaceView so It intercepts the click of the place he is located, but I want this behaviour only when onLongClick, if simple onClick I do not want want it to react.

Comment: `fab.setOnClickListener(null)`can you try this code

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that you don't want the FAB to prevent clicking on the view behind it, you can just delegate the click event on to the other view using a touch listener to prevent the "click" behavior:

```
fab.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
    surfaceView.performOnClick() // Pretend the other view was clicked
    return true // Consume event to prevent "click"
}

fab.setOnLongClickListener {
    doMoreImportantThings()
}
```

Comment: Seems legit, I will check it out soon. If it works then I will mark ur answer as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: It does not work. It is related either with another usage of this class than I expected: com.nambimobile.widgets.efab.ExpandableFab or my a bit complicated custom GestureListener that is responsible for supporting onTouchEvent(ev). But anyway I abandoned idea of this FAB, I will make it another way. Thanks!